# Scrollbar adding padding tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm trying to place scrollbars inside a tkinter listbox, but every time I add them a huge amount of space is added to the top of the master window.

Below are a few snippets from my app. The first just generates the listbox and, as you can see from the first linked image below, the result is a nice, flush window. However, when I add the scrollbars from the second snippet, large amounts of space are placed at the top of the window.

```
#Create a listbox and fill with the data found in a dictionary called "d"
self.dataDisplay = Listbox(root, font = ("helvetica, 14"))
                    
self.subfields = list(d.keys()) #d is a dictionary that is built elsewhere
                
for i in range(len(self.subfields)): #iterate through each dictionary item
      dataType = type(d[self.subfields[i]])
      self.dataDisplay.insert(END, str(helpers.displayHandler(self, self.subfields[i], str(dataType)))) #fill the listbox using a helper function called displayHandler that simply formats the data as a string

self.dataDisplay.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
```

The above code works great and, along with the rest of the code in my app, displays a window that looks like this:
[No scrollbars, no extra padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw0vk.png)

Adding the following few lines of code to put scrollbars in the listbox, causes a huge amount of padding to be added to the top of the window.

```
scrollbarY = Scrollbar(self.dataDisplay, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbarY.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarX = Scrollbar(self.dataDisplay, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbarX.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
self.dataDisplay.config(xscrollcommand = scrollbarX.set)
scrollbarY.config(command=self.dataDisplay.yview)
scrollbarX.config(command=self.dataDisplay.xview)
```

The result is the following:
[Scrollbars, extra padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFvmD.png)

I know that not being able to provide all the code in my app may limit possible answers, but I'm hoping someone can at least explain why simply adding scrollbars to the listbox widget can effect the properties of other parts of the app. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. We don't need all the code, but we need an example program that exhibits the same problem. Creating this program will help you narrow down the cause of the problem. I don't know if it's related, but you shouldn't be putting scrollbars inside the listbox, they will end up hiding some of the data.

Comment: @BryanOakley, taking the scrollbars out of the listbox widget actually fixed the problem, thanks for the help.